# Find the lcm(a,b,c) given two conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a problem in a Italian competion of three years ago. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Given $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{1}{58}  $$
and 
$$a+b+c=2010$$

Find the $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)$

I'm trying to solve this problem without any use of software, and I would like to prove it with an elegant proof. Thanks!

Comment: Three year old competition problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: It will be some permutation of $a = 90$, $b = 180$, $c = 1740$

Comment: Hence $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)$= 5220.
@Cocopuffs How do you arrive at your answer?

Comment: A quick Python program. I don't think that's what the OP is looking for though

Comment: Yes, its a maths competition question as rightly said by @Harald Hanche-Olsen. Hence no calculator allowed, and certainly no computer program. This ought to be done in less than 2 minutes using only a pencil and some paper, and I'm very curious as to how to tackle problems like this.

Comment: Yes it was a math competition in Italy. The problem is that I cannot find a very elegant proof for this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algebraically manipulating:
$$58(ab+bc+ac)-abc=0$$
$$58^3-58^2(a+b+c)+58(ab+bc+ac)-abc=58^3-58^2(a+b+c)$$
$$(58-a)(58-b)(58-c)=58^2(58-2010)$$
$$(a-58)(b-58)(c-58)=58^2(1952)$$
$$(a-58)(b-58)(1952-a-b)=2^7*29^2*61$$
Replacing conviniently:
$$x=a-58,y=b-58$$
$$xy(1836-x-y)=2^7*29^2*61$$
Then you only have to choose $x$ and $y$ as divisors of the number, check if the final equation holds, replace for $a$ and $b$, and calculate the $lcm$.

Comment: So what you've essentially done is to take the polynomial that has $a,b,c$ as roots, and then evaluated it at 58.  This is very nice and does get the answer, but it's still a bit unsatisfying to have to check so many cases at the end.  Also, one is left wondering why the problem setter asked for the lcm, suggesting that s/he believed the lcm of the roots is easier to find than the roots themselves.  I wonder if we're still missing something.

Comment: Yes, it is cumbersome to check $(7+1)*(2+1)*(1+1)=48$ possible cases for $x$ and then try to solve for $y$ in the integers. I think that choosing the values for $x$ *appropiately* (starting from the lowest divisors) and assuming numerical skills are tested in the competition, this would be just in the limit of acceptability. Anyway, I can't find a way to solve the problem to the $lcm$ of $a$, $b$, and $c$ without actually calculating them. Maybe some cutoffs can be made in the choosing of $x$ and $y$, and that would simplify the problem to a smaller bunch of cases.

Comment: For example, $AM \ge GM$ doesn't help very much in stablishing useful bounds. Divisibility conditions and simmetry like if $x$ is even and $y$ is odd, then necessarily $x=2^7*a$, do help in cutting some cases. That is the best tools for cutting off some cases that I can think of.